# ionic 2: export app to iphone without Mac

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to export my ionic 2 app with this code

```
ionic run ios
```

but I get this error

> ✗ You cannot run iOS unless you are on Mac OSX.

I'm using a PC since I'm not MAC user, I am a little stuck with that.
what can I do?

Comment: You will either need to get a Mac or get access to a Mac

Comment: Unfortunately it's true, there's Apple is very restrictive regarding building apps for iOS. Main problem here is the signing process. Not a long time ago, it wasn't even on a Mac possible to build an iOS app unless you paid for being an Apple dev. Right now, you have one personal certificate you might use, but still only on a Mac. If you are an Apple Dev though, there might be a small(!) chance to get your app up and running, check this article: https://web.archive.org/web/20150303180446/http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac

Comment: THIS ISNT POSSIBLE WITHOUT MAC.

Comment: Yes it is, download VirtualBox and a viable Mac OS VM, this way you trick your pc into thinking you're on a mac

Comment: Thank you ivaro18

Answer (score 0):

I succeed to do that by installing virtual machine on window then install os. 
that works fine.